# How to make a JavaScript function more concise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to StackOverflow and needed some help with the following JavaScript, jQuery question.

Is there a more concise way to code the following?:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$("#article1").click(function(){
    showarticleDescription(id=1);
})

$("#article2").click(function(){
    showarticleDescription(id=2);
})

$("#article3").click(function(){
    showarticleDescription(id=3);
})

$("#article4").click(function(){
    showarticleDescription(id=4);
})

$("#article5").click(function(){
    showarticleDescription(id=5);
})
})
```

Comment: Why in the world are you doing `showarticleDescription(id=1)` (or any other number)? While this isn't invalid syntax, this isn't Python either and there isn't any key value thing going on here; the closest thing you'll get are objects.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry. Just trying to learn here!

Comment: That's fine. Everyone makes mistakes when learning :P

Comment: Also I'm passing the id value to the function and after assigning it to the variable, I am also using it in the lines of code that follow. Hence, id=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the starts with CSS selector:

```js
$('[id^="article"]').click(function() {
  showarticleDescription(+this.id.substr(this.id.length - 1));
});
```

It'd be better though to apply a common class here (and possibly use a custom attribute). In the HTML you can do something like:

```html
<div data-article="1" class="article">...</div>
<div data-article="2" class="article">...</div>
<div data-article="3" class="article">...</div>
```

```js
$("article").click(function() {
  const article = +$(this).data("article");
  showarticleDescription(article);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add classes and data attributes to your elements (rather than relying on ids) and use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to capture the click events as they "bubble up" the DOM, and then call the function.

```js
function showarticleDescription() {
  console.log($(this).data('id'))
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '.article', showarticleDescription);
});
```

```css
.article:hover { cursor: pointer; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="1" class="article">One</div>
<div data-id="2" class="article">Two</div>
<div data-id="3" class="article">Three</div>
```